# Remove page count from WooCommerce search page title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, page-title

When navigating to the next page of search results in Woocommerce, the title shows as

> Search results: “example” – Page 2

I would like to know how I can customise this so the page number is not shown. Ideally, it would be nice to be displayed as

> Search results for Example

I have looked in the files and this title seems to be called using

```
<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>
```

So there's not much there for me to work on.

There are lots of posts on removing the title all together, nothing on how to customise it.

Comment: Why not add pagination in a session instead of post/get?

Comment: Please have a look on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225724/how-to-customize-search-result-page-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use [`woocommerce_page_title`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_page_title/) hook to alter the title
>   according to your need.

Here is a working code:

```
// define the woocommerce_page_title callback 
function filter_woocommerce_page_title($page_title)
{
    if (is_search())
    {
        $page_title = 'Search results for ' . ucfirst(get_search_query());
    }
    return $page_title;
}

// add the filter 
add_filter('woocommerce_page_title', 'filter_woocommerce_page_title', 10, 1);
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: @CharlyAnderson: I have added `ucfirst()` also for making first letter in Uppercase.